# Security Certificate issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a strange situation where on some PCs in the network visiting a site I can get through just fine but on some of the PCs I get "There is a problem with this websites security certificate" error and I have to accept an *untrusted* certificate. The untrusted is basically the localhost.localdomain and on PCs that it works I get the actual certificate.

does anyone else face this issue?

I checked the date and time, and the url but none of those are the problem.

Please advice.

thanks

Comment: Internet Explorer displays exact certificate issue. For example, name mismatch, untrusted root, etc. Can you tell exact failure reason? BTW, name "localhost.localdomain" makes no sense, as localhost is an alias to a local computer.

Comment: I found out that, there were two certs for this application in two different servers. So the root cert was OK, yet the other cert in the sub directory was expired. :)